# Display Activity over lock screen android

Tags: android, android-intent, lockscreen

I am trying to display my alarm activity over lock screen. I am using a full screen intent from my broadcast receiver. When the screen is locked, the activity is not displayed over lock screen. It is displayed when i unlock the screen. Where am i going wrong?

I have used following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

In the activity, i am setting following flags in the activity's oncreate:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) 
     getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            if(keyguardManager!=null)
                keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
        } else {
            getWindow().addFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
            );
        }
```

Comment: I have mentioned it is meant for displaying alarm. So it is a good reason to display activity over Lock Screen. Secondly there are many occasions  we need to display activity over Lock Screen - while receiving voip calls. Hope you uninstall WhatsApp and stop using android phone !

Comment: That makes sense.